# ag-grid - how ng-model works

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, angularjs-ng-model

This question came to my mind because I am stuck in a situation where I need to have a column which is nothing but a checkbox (this check box is not for row selection).

From backend I get values true/false and I have to map this value to this checkbox.

I am using template or cellRenderer to show checkbox in the column but value never maps to the checkbox.

Here is how I am writing the template:

```
template:'<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isValid"></input>'
```

How can I map the value to checkbox in this case?

Comment: The simplest way is to add the checkbox value to the rowData and then in the column's cellrenderer, read the value from the parameter and set the value of input accordingly.
If you have to use ng-model, then you will need to bind the value to `$scope` and call `$compile()` to generate the element with the scope binding in it.

Comment: I used the cellRenderer to create the element and then return the created element :)